# jQuery .animate queue does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, jquery-animate

[Dreamweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) gives an error. What's the right syntax?

After the first

> .animate({left: '-=980'}, 550,

?

The real deal is: That I can only use one ".animate({left: '-=980'}, 550," in this code... There comes an error if I want to add two (or more) .animate's in the animation queue.

BTW: The "clicknr" variable and the 'disabled' CSS class - are just flags for some internal process.

```
$('#fwdShowroom').click(function() {
    $button = $(this);
    if ( clicknr != 1 )  {
        if( !$button.hasClass( 'disabled' ) ) {
            $button.addClass( 'disabled' );
            clicknr -= 1,
              $('#showroom ul')
                .animate({left: '-=985'}, 550,
                     Dreamweaver says: Error on this line        .animate({left: '+=5'},200,
                function() { $button.removeClass('disabled') });
        }
    }
});
```

The needed effect is: That the "#showroom ul" DIV smoothly moves forward and then goes smoothly some pixels back to create a nice physical motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the closing parentheses `)` in the first `animate` call:

```
.animate({left: '-=985'},550)
```